# add a new column with a constant into a file

Tags: csh

I have a file with 108 lines and 3 columns. I want to add each line a 0 (in the fourth column) in cshell. 
like from this

```
11443 225 3 
1245645 22 3
18966 2975 3 
...
```

to this

```
11443 225 3 0
1245645 22 3 0
18966 2975 3 0
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to append `0` to the end of each line, this is probably done most easily with `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/\s*$/ 0/' YOUR_FILE
11443 225 3 0
1245645 22 3 0
18966 2975 3 0
```

This only displays the changed data, to directly modify the file in-place, add the `-i` flag:

```
sed -i 's/\s*$/ 0/' YOUR_FILE
```

What this `sed` command does is to match the regex pattern `\s*$` (matches the line end plus any number of trailing whitespace characters) on each line and replace it with the string  `0`.

Comment: and if I have one number in  txt file, how can I add it into every line?

Comment: You mean you have a file with content e.g. `42` and then you want to append `42` to each line of the other file instead of 0?

Comment: Does `\s*$` really match anything that plain `$` doesn't?

Comment: It matches trailing whitespace. The only reason why I added it is to strip trailing spaces and replace them with a single space instead. @steeldriver